# Running Google Storage Command from within Google Cloud Functions (JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Cloud Functions to move the entire content of a folder in GCS to another folder in the same bucket. I'm using Javascript.
Although the bucket and source object exist, I keep getting an error that the object does not exist.

This is the Cloud Function code:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

async function moveFile() {
  // Moves the file within the bucket
  await storage
    .bucket("my-bucket")
    .file("folder/source/**")
    .move("folder/target/**");

  console.log(
    `gs://${bucketName}/${srcFilename} moved to gs://${bucketName}/${destFilename}.`
  );
}
exports.moveContent = (req, res) => {
   moveFile().catch(console.error);
  res.send("done")
}
```

This is the source of package.json

```
{
  "name": "move-content",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "googleapis": "37.1.0",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^4.5.0"
  }
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting (From Google Logs):

```
move-content 3m89p16m58bb { Error: file#copy failed with an error - No such object: my-bucket/folder/source/** at new ApiError (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:58:15) at Util.parseHttpRespBody (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:193:38) at Util.handleResp
...
```

What am I missing...?

Thanks

Comment: How many files do you have to move?

Comment: can be tens to a several hundreds

Comment: If you have timeout issue because of too many files, don't hesitate to post another question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you appear to be using wildcards.  I believe that these wildcards apply to the tool called `gsutil`.  [Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames) is an article of gsutil wildcards.

If we look at the API of the Node.js client, we don't see any description of similar wildcards.  For example, the `file` function of the `bucket` object says that the name is:

> The name of the file in this bucket.

If you want to move multiple files, it looks like you have to perform a `getFiles` API call (see [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles)).  This returns a promise that resolves to an array of file objects.  You can then iterate over each file object and perform a `move` API call (see [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#move)) on each one.

This story would appear to be consistent with the error message you get.

Comment: BTW, do you know if it is possible to use a wildcard in  `bigquery.dataset.table.load` function in order to load multiple files in parallel?

Comment: To your BQ question ... looking at the API here ... https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/Table.html#load seems to show an asynchronous load of only one file.  However, I'm not seeing any comments that would say you couldn't run as many calls to this function (one per source file) as desired.  Since these are non blocking ... we should be ok.